# Authorization: Bearer + Token Issue

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-resource-manager

I am working on Azure API.

I need to get all Virtual Machines list and need to do action like START STOP RESTART.

When I am trying to get list of all subscriptions from this link its working fine:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/resources/subscriptions/list

But from my API I got null result.

I Identified the issue and the issue is **Authorization: Bearer +  Token Issue**

When I am passing static Authorization: Bearer Token. Its working fine in my api but when I am getting authorization token from CURL its return null data.

I am using below code for getting access token.

```
$strAppTenantDomainName="exmple.com"; // This is tenant domain name
$arrCurlOptions[CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS] = ['client_id'=> 'xxxxxx','client_secret'=> 'xxxxxx','resource'=> "https://management.azure.com/",'grant_type'=> 'client_credentials'];

$arrAccessTokenDetails = cUrl_process("https://login.microsoftonline.com/$strAppTenantDomainName/oauth2/token",$arrCurlOptions);
```

Please help me with this.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I can reproduce your issue, I suppose you have not added your AD App as a role in the subscription.

[image]

To fix the issue, navigate to your subscription in the portal -> `Access control (IAM)` -> `Add role assignment`-> add your AD App as an `owner` role(for example).

Then it will work fine.

[image]
For more details, refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/quickstart-assign-role-user-portal).

Comment: But I can get all the subscription from microsoft url.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/resources/subscriptions/list

@joy-wang